# cannot convert 'float*' to 'float'

Tags: c, arrays, return-type, function-declaration, incompatibletypeerror

```c
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float array(float a[],int n);

int main() {
    int k=5;
    float a[k+1];
    array(a[k+1],k);
}

float array(float a[],int n )// n = size of array
{
    printf("enter elements in order of increasing:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("array[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);  
    }
    return a;
}
```

I want to build a program for using a function to give an array with increasing float numbers but it has a bug and the compiler shows these errors:

```
[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float' in return9
[Error] cannot convert 'float' to 'float*' for argument '1' to 'float array(float*, int)'
```

Comment: Note that `array(a[k+1],k);` is passing *one illegal element* of the array. Please try `array(a, k);` You ignore the function's `return` value anyway, and it is not really necessary unless you want to communicate some status.

Comment: Before this becomes a crippling habit, you really need to abandon this absurd indentation style. There are many [conventional indentation styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) in common use, and while they vary in popularity, none of them indent the body of the function to the end of the function signature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a` is of type `float*`, the return type is `float`. You either need to return *one* float, or convert the return type to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

For starters you are passing a non-existent element of the array with the index `k + 1` to the function

```
array(a[k+1],k);
```

The expression `a[k+1]` has the type `float` while the function expects an object of the type `float *`. You need to call the function like

```
array( a, k + 1 );
      ^^^ ^^^^^
```

also because actually the array declared with `k+1` element.

```
float a[k+1];
```

However it is unclear why the variable k is declared with the initializer `5` while the array is declared with k + 1 elements that is with 6 elements. It would be more logically consistent if the number of elements would be equal to the value of `k`. For example

```
int k = 5; // or int k = 6
float a[k];
array( a, k )
```

The function is declared with the return type `float`

```
float array(float a[],int n);
```

but the function actually returns an object of the type `float *`.

```
float array(float a[],int n )// n = size of array
{
    //...
    return a;
}
```

The return type of the function does not make great sense. Declare the function as having the return type `void`.

```
void array(float a[],int n);

//...

void array(float a[],int n )// n = size of array
{
    printf("enter elements in order of increasing:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("array[%d]:",i);
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors are rather descriptive.

1. To pass `a` as the first argument you simply need to write

```c
    array(a, k);
```

Note that `a[k+1]` is a non-existent element with index `k+1`, `k` being the largest one, so this expression actually invokes an UB.

2. If you want to return the whole array, declare function to have return type of `float *`, not a single `float`.